# Subscription with restrictions of time and quantity

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

We are developing an iOS application for audio books. We are looking to add a subscription plan, where we can allow the user to buy two books in one month of subscription and other plans like that?

Can someone tell us that? Is this according to apple in app guidelines. I was not able to found any reference like this on store where an in app purchase have limit to number of items with time.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

For such a case, I would suggest to add it as an ***Auto-Renewable Subscription*** In-App Purchase:

> A product that allows users to purchase dynamic content **for a set**
>   **period**. This type of subscription renews automatically unless
>   cancelled by the user.
>
> Example: Monthly subscription for an app offering a streaming service.

and for solving the issue of the quantity, you might need to let the server-side to handle it for each user.

So, the generic solution would be to: add the purchase as Auto-Renewable Subscription (for the determining of period restriction) and during this period, I assume that checking the number of purchased books for each user would be easy on the server-side.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad for your reply ... I was just curious to know whether this allowed by apple or not ... I am really scared of rejection from them .

Comment: @ArvindMishra logically, it should be no problem referring to this issue.

Comment: @ArvindMishra btw, since you seems that you are a new user to stack overflow, I would invite you to accept answers (green tick) for answers that solved your issue; This leads to: add +2 points to your reputation, +15 to answerer  reputation and the most important thing is it gives indication to the viewers that this is how such an issue should be solved.